# Apex: Email invocation not working in sandbox

Tags: apex, apex-email-service

I want to send out alert emails to account team members when their account(s) contracts are up for renewal 120 days from 'today'. I have test accounts created to meet the soql criteria, I'm in the account team in all of em but I'm getting no emails. Below is my apex code. Any help will be appreciated :)

```
public with sharing class AccountRenewalReminder{

Account[] accounts;
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> msgList;

public AccountRenewalReminder(){

    msgList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    accounts = new List<Account>([SELECT Name, OwnerId, Account_Id__c, Carrier_Id__c, Contract_Renewal_Date__c, Type FROM Account WHERE X120_Day_Renewal_Reminder__c = TODAY AND Termination_Date__c = NULL AND Contract_Executed_on_Client__c = 'Yes' LIMIT 50000]);

    Id emailTemplateId = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = 'Account_90_Contract_Renewal'].Id;

    if(!accounts.isEmpty()){

        for(Account a : accounts){

            for(AccountTeamMember atm : a.AccountTeamMembers){

                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                email.setTemplateId(emailTemplateId);
                email.setTargetObjectId(atm.UserId);
                email.setBccSender(false);
                email.setUseSignature(false);
                email.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Team');
                email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                String[] ccList = new List<String>();
                ccList.add(System.Label.UserEmailId);
                //email.setCcAddresses(ccList);

                msgList.add(email);

                System.debug('***********************'+ msgList);
            }
        }
    }

    if(msgList.size() > 0){
        Messaging.sendEmail(msgList);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Make sure that you have the email access level set to **All Email**. The setting is found in **Setup** | **Email Administration** | **Deliveribility**. The setting defaults to **No Access** when a sandbox is created. Also make sure that the users email addresses are correct as they get changed as well when the sandbox is created

Comment: Email settings are configured correctly and double checked before posting. Thank you

Comment: I see you have a debug statement to output the msgList.  Are there messages in the list in the debug statement?

Comment: Shouldn't your SOQL query on account also include `AccountTeamMembers`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not querying `AccountTeamMembers` when you are querying the `Account` records. The loop below is never executed because of this

```
for(AccountTeamMember atm : a.AccountTeamMembers){
```